# Extract a sum of table1.column2 where table1.column1 contains value from table2.column2

Tags: mysql, sql, join, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to build a database similar to the structure in the picture

[image: target]

I tried using this code but it doesn't seem to work.

```
 SELECT wp_wpdatatable_4.remaining, wp_wpdatatable_7.name
    FROM wp_wpdatatable_4
    INNER JOIN wp_wpdatatable_7
        ON wp_wpdatatable_7.name LIKE CONCAT(wp_wpdatatable_4.techsname, '%');
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your picture has table1 and table2, but the code wp_wpdatatable_4 and wp_wpdatatable_7. Poor names anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, just interchange the field names.

You are trying to query `John Smith LIKE 'John Smith CTE 555-555-5555%'` which will never be true.

This will be true `John Smith CTE 555-555-5555 LIKE 'John Smith%'`

Here is corrected query

```
SELECT wp_wpdatatable_4.remaining, wp_wpdatatable_7.name
FROM wp_wpdatatable_4
INNER JOIN wp_wpdatatable_7
ON wp_wpdatatable_4.techsname LIKE CONCAT(wp_wpdatatable_7.name, ' %');
```

*Note: added space before % to ensure word match*

**Update**

To sum values in remaining column, use `GROUP BY`. Here is the updated query:

```
SELECT SUM(wp_wpdatatable_4.remaining) AS total_remaining, wp_wpdatatable_7.name
FROM wp_wpdatatable_4
INNER JOIN wp_wpdatatable_7
ON wp_wpdatatable_4.techsname LIKE CONCAT(wp_wpdatatable_7.name, ' %')
GROUP BY wp_wpdatatable_7.name;
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but how do I do so the values in 'remaining' get summed instead of displaying the first value as in 
`SELECT wp_wpdatatable_4.remaining, wp_wpdatatable_7.name
FROM wp_wpdatatable_4
INNER JOIN wp_wpdatatable_7
ON wp_wpdatatable_4.techsname LIKE CONCAT(wp_wpdatatable_7.name, ' %')
GROUP BY wp_wpdatatable_7.name;`

Comment: Have updated my POST with query to sum values in `remaining` column.

Answer (score 0):

Use wildcards on wp_wpdatatable_7.name:

```
SELECT wp_wpdatatable_4.remaining, wp_wpdatatable_7.name
FROM wp_wpdatatable_4
INNER JOIN wp_wpdatatable_7 
ON wp_wpdatatable_4.techsname like '%wp_wpdatatable_7.name%'
```